# Emulate TP-Link WR841N using Qemu

Tags: mips, qemu, emulation

I have downloaded a few different versions of the firmware from the TP-Link website. I've been piecing together details on how to achieve this but I'm missing some key points.

Following instructions from devttys0 and their great blog, used binwalk to unpack the firmware.

Following some details picked up from this previous question [[Emulate TP-LINK WR740N with QEMU](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4480/emulate-tp-link-wr740n-with-qemu]) I've attempted to bot using the Malta debian kernel.

The issue I've had with the previous question was that there was never a final example of the arguments supplied to Qemu.

```
qemu-system-mips -M malta -kernel '/media/sf__share/vmlinux-2.6.32-5-4kc-malta' -nographic -append "init=/sbin/init root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0,115200" -hda 'myFileSystem.img'
```

as well as (init=/bin/sh):

```
qemu-system-mips -M malta -kernel '/media/sf__share/vmlinux-2.6.32-5-4kc-malta' -nographic -append "init=/bin/sh root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0,115200" -hda 'myFileSystem.img'
```

In almost all cases I get:

```
Warning: unable to open an initial console.
```

I'm happy to accept some pointers on what I might be missing?

My objective is to create an emulated MIPS Linux instance with the rootfs extracted from the firmware image. I then have further plans, but outside the scope of my initial issues.